# what would be the correct way how to manage multiple logins from one user account in nodejs, express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session, connect-mongo

I'm using express-session, passport and connect-mongo for save sessions in mongodb.
my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {        
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.5",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "chalk": "^2.4.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
        "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
        "clockwork": "^0.1.4",
        "compression": "^1.7.4",
        "connect-mongo": "^2.0.3",
        "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
        "errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
        "express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
        "express-session": "^1.15.6",
        "express-session-passport-cleanup": "^1.0.3",
        "express-status-monitor": "^1.2.3",
        "express-validator": "^5.3.1",          
        "lastfm": "^0.9.3",
        "lob": "^6.0.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "lusca": "^1.6.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "node-linkedin": "^0.5.6",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.0.0",
        "passport": "^0.4.0", 
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",   
        "pug": "^2.0.3",
        "request": "^2.88.0",
        "stripe": "^6.28.0",           
        "uuid": "^3.3.2",
        "validator": "^10.11.0"
    },
```

this works fine and its posible multiple logins from same user account, in the same browser in incognito or with other browsers or different devices , but i dont know if  what is the correct way to management this .  I so as not to generate errorsbetween the sessions of the same user and with the shopping cart storage.

how is the standard manament way to handle multiple logins from one user account, I mean to have on the sessions always linked to the last updated data and also to the store, so that mistakes do not happen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to understand the concept of how the session works.

The session will be a unique identifier is stored on the client side (called a "session id"). This session id is passed to the web server every time the browser makes an HTTP request (ie a page link or AJAX request). The web application match incoming session id with it's an internal database(redis etc) and retrieves the stored variables for use by the requested page.

So, If you logged in using the same account to different browser the stored session information will be unique(based on session id). You don't need to worries about it.

Comment: thanks for answering @narayansharma91, sorry if I´am explaining myself bad, that i think that I understand it,  but still have doubts

1-  there is some standard for multiple logon support for the same user?

2- Is it necessary to limit the number of sessions to a user can log in at the same time? as a maximum I mean

3- How do I make the sessions work with the latest shopping cart data?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to display shopping card information to both browsers if someone logged in to different browsers right?

Comment: if that's one of the things I was referring to,
but I already know how to do it, the other is how I have to do so that when one of the active sessions of the same user changes the password the other sessions are invalidated, express-session  having any way of handling this? I can do it on my own, delete the active sessions except the one that changed the password but i dont know if this into conflicts with express-session, 
Any suggestions?

thanks for answering